# H2O: GLM MOJO models doesn't hold variable importance?

Tags: python-3.x, h2o, h2o4gpu

A question on h2o mojo models.

Is my understanding correct that GLM MOJO models don't hold variable importance for the model?

Or is there something that am missing?

I get the below message on screenshot sometimes when I query varimp/varimp_plot from the GLM model.

***"Warning: This model doesn't have variable importance."***

Is this usual? while we get varimp from the same model within the kernel which generated them. Just curious to understand this.

Any leads would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MOJO models are H2O's primary way of taking models into production. These self-contained zip files are primarily meant to be run via `genmodel` and not inspected. MOJO model does not equal binary model, which is tied to a certain H2O version. The reason for that is simple - algorithm parameters and the algorithm itself may change between versions.

Anyway, H2O provides a way to import MOJOs back into H2O and **primarily** use them for scoring. Some attributes of MOJOs are still extracted from the MOJO and provided to the user. But, as the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html#mojo-models) says, it is not guaranteed which model parameters are exposed and some might be missing. MOJO model import is implemented as a part of H2O's `Generic model` functionality - the ability of H2O to "embrace" any model, even the ones trained outside H2O, provided the "Generic model driver" is available.

With that said, there is definitely a way to provide variable importances to MOJO import functionality users. This is a known problem already and is tracked in [H2O JIRA](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7606).

More resources on MOJO model on [my blog](https://www.pavel.cool/h2o-3/h2o-mojo-import/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, Pavel. That helps. Hope we get an update soon with it fixed.